# jquery as a local resource

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use the following header

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

There is no error in my HTML file. But I am facing a problem. Every time I am loading this page , there is the need for internet connectivity.

I have developed an webpage through which some instruments would be controlled through node.js acting as a server. This would be accesible in the intranet (between local computers in LAN) only.

Is there any method to use jquery as a local resource, i.e. If i download and save these files and use it from the local hard disk.

I saved both the files jquery-1.8.3.js and jquery-ui.js in the same folder as the html and used it with `<script src="/jquery-ui.js"></script>`  it is giving resource not found 404 error.

Comment: the header i used is   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> with no errors

Comment: Really! Of course you can load the jQuery file from your local server or wherever, you just messed up the URL or filename, that's why it's returning 404 ***File not found*** !

Comment: put jquery-*.js files under your public directory (htdocs) and just include "jquery-*.js" (replace * appropriately).

Comment: Why is the question even tagged node.js and ajax? Removing it now.

Comment: @Monoj - Can u please explain in detail. My server.js file is in c:\arduinojs. My Html file is in c:\arduinojs\pages. Can u please tell me where to keep these .js files

Answer (score 3):

If the .js file is in the same folder as the .html, then you should be able to include it with

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the jquery and put it in your scripts folder and use like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

This will first check for the CDN if exist it will load from CDN other wise it will take local  one

uses of CDN are in this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/)